# nested ng-repeats in angular not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some nested controllers each called with ng-repeat.

The bottom level item has the ability to remove itself which it does via a ng-click event. This event splices the item from the array.

In the plunkr below, if you delete the second item (item2), then the array is left with item1 and item3, but the view sees item1 and item2. The sub controllers are never called again and the cached controllers are used.

How can I manually force these controllers to be refreshed? Shouldn't angular do this for me?

http://plnkr.co/edit/jDidC4anikwjZSLMWct6?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently tracking by `$index` which will not update the way you want:

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x6YDRV?p=preview).

The only change I made was to take out the `track by $index` in `pitem in items track by $index` (`toplevel.html`):

```
<div ng-repeat="pitem in items" ng-include="" src="'mid-level.html'" ng-controller="midlevel">test</div>
```

**EDIT:**

`track by $index` will use the `$index` value as the equality check when deciding what to update in the `ng-repeat`.  So this is what is happening:

1. After set up we have `[i: 0, name: 'item1', i: 1, name: 'item2', i: 2, name: 'item3']`
2. `item2` is spliced out
3. `track by $index` sees there has been a change and checks if `$index` with value `0` and `1` still exist in the array
4. They do, so no update is performed
5. However `$index` with value `3` is not there
6. So, it is updated and removed

Comment: Also why using the syntacs `ng-include="" src="'mid-level.html'"` when you can use directly `ng-include"'mid-level.html'"`

Comment: Thanks very much!!! Is there any documentation about why the track by is not working as I expect?

Comment: @MatB I have added a detailed breakdown of how using `$index` is breaking the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is you are making check on item.name, but you are storing updated list in pitems.name, so if you update your code in mid-level.html from

```
{{item.name}} <span ng-click="delete(items, $index)">x</span>
```

to

```
{{pitem.name}} <span ng-click="delete(items, $index)">x</span>
```

this is working fine.